# I'm able to create repository with Logic App, but default main branch not creating

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I'm able to create repository with Logic App, but default main branch not creating. Please help.

[image]

When i go inside newly created repo, its asking to Initialize the main branch manually,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps REST API "[**Repositories - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" can only create an empty repository which is not initialized with any file.

To automatic initialize the new repository, you need to also call the REST API "[**Pushes - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" to add (push) a **`README`** file to initialize the repository with a **`main`** branch.

##### Request URI

```http
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=7.0
```

**Note:** It also is okay to pass the repository name to **`{repositoryId}`**.

##### Request Body

```json
{
    "refUpdates": [
        {
            "name": "refs/heads/main",
            "oldObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "commits": [
        {
            "comment": "Added README.md",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "changeType": "add",
                    "item": {
                        "path": "/README.md"
                    },
                    "newContentTemplate": {
                        "name": "README.md",
                        "type": "readme"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```